# After cicking button its not showing any shape in my panel

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, custom-painting

I am trying to draw rectangle in my panel. Below it is my graphics class:

```
class MyComponent extends JComponent {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {        
        g.fillRect(30, 30, 100, 100);         
    }   
 }
```

And I have rectangle button where I add this action Listener

```
rect.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
```

And my action implementations is:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==rect)
        {               
            p1.add(new MyComponent()); 
            p1.repaint();           
        }
    }   
}
```

But when I click rectangle button nothing happens.

Comment: Side note: you should not override `paint()` but `paintComponent()` instead. And don't forget to call `super.paintComponent()`. See [A Closer Lookt at the Paint Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Comment: I change it to that Still it is not working

Comment: Depending on the layout manager of p1,  MyComponent may not display because it has no default size. You should also override the getPreferredSize method of MyComponent class to return an appropriate size...

Answer (score 3):

`revalidate` needs to be called before `repaint`

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Typically `paintComponent` is overridden instead of `paint` in Swing with `super.paintComponent` being called to update child components

Comment: Depending on the layout manager, MyComponent may not be displayed even when using this, the OP should be overriding the getPreferredSize method as well...+1

Comment: Good catch on `revalidate()` the panel. +1